# Edit Adobe Photoshop PSD file on Linux

Tags: linux, image-editing, svg, image-conversion, psd

I have a design that was provided in Photoshop PSD format, and I want to modify the design, but I don't have Photoshop.

How can I modify PSD on Linux?

Migrating from PSD to SVG is the best solution if there are tools for this. The design does not need to be saved back to PSD.

- Free, ideally open source
- Runs on Linux
- No or minimal design information loss

Answer (score 6):

You can use GIMP (PSD format is [documented](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/)) although you might lose some information in the process [such as](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=825934):

1. Layer comps
2. Layer effects (shadow, glow, etc)
3. Vector objects
4. Layer masks

Comment: Too obvious how it meets the other specified requirements: Free, Open-Source, runs on Linux – everybody knows Gimp does :) I second this recommendation (+1).

Comment: Oh, just as an aside, GIMP is not great at handling CMYK - so if your PSD is in that, convert it to RGB first if possible..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Gimp is not suitable for working with 9x% of graphics professionals.  It will not open many PSD files at all, and gets the colors and layers info wrong on some that it will open.

The closest thing to a 'solution', of which I am aware, is to use a Virtual Box running Windows.  Even an old XP-compatible (2006) version of Photoshop will open everything that has been thrown at me.  Gimp hasn't caught up to that year in the PSD department, sadly.

Please someone tell me I am wrong, as I waste a lot of time with this setup.

--Edit

Further digging found this:

[psd to png - software or website that converts all the components?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/psd-to-png-software-or-website-that-concerts-all-the-components/9814#9814)

... indicating you can use imagemagick's 'convert' command to pull out all the layers separately.   This is better than nothing, though if you need to capture a select-set of layers, together, in context, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to work with SVG files, you should use [Inkscape](https://www.inkscape.org) (even on Windows). It is a vector editor built around the file format.

Inkscape can't take .PSD file formats - for that you can either deal witht he subset supported by [GIMP](http://gimp.org), as pointed out in other answers, or try oppening then in [Krita](http://krita.org) (though I don't know how their support for PSD is - it should at least open CMYK layers)

Comment: I use Inkscape all the time. But here the design was provided as PSD.