# psd to png - software or website that converts all the components?

Tags: image-conversion, psd

I have a PSD file with a lot of components. The only site I found for converting it to components is [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/), but it doesn't allow me to download all of the components at once and the other sites/software I have found only give me a flattened image as a single PNG. Does someone know of a website or software for this?

Comment: "the other sites/software" -> can you provide the list?

Comment: By components you do mean layers right? and you want to export each layer as a separate png file yes? Do you have any version of Photoshop (ie would a photoshop plugin work)?

Comment: @NickWilde yes. and i dont have photoshop...no other ways?

Comment: @User6413: I'm sure there are other way's possible - whether there are other ways easy I'm not sure of hand; but probably someone knows an easy way. Just was asking to narrow it down whether that would work for you.

Comment: Which OS do you use? [tag:windows], [tag:osx] or [tag:linux]?

Answer (score 8):

**1. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)**

This one is a command-line tool, available for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X. To export layers separately to individual PNG files, you can run the following command after installing it:

```
convert Boring.psd Cool.png
```

That will result in `Cool-0.png`, `Cool-1.png`, etc. for each layer.

For a flattened image you need to add the corresponding switch:

```
convert Boring.psd -flatten Cool.png
```

---

**2. [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/downloads):**

Some Photoshop fans call it *an advanced MS Paint*! But it is a decent image editing tool, released under LGPLv3 and GPLv3+ licenses and is available for Linux, OS X, and Windows, and it's free!

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132946/gimp-editing-psd-file-saving-single-layer-as-png)'s a tutorial on how to convert each layer of a PSD to PNG files using GIMP.

Alternatively, you can install [Export_Layers plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/18440) to do it faster.

Comment: As far as I know this will flatten the image and save as png, but the OP wants to extract layers from a psd file and save them as individual png files.

Comment: Aw! Then that's the wrong tutorial, thanks for mentioning it @nidunc. Am updating the answer now. (:

Answer (score 3):

You could use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) in combination with the [Export Layers as PNG plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/18440).
However, installing plugins in GIMP is not an easy task.
Luckily I found another way of doing what you want:

#### [PSDParse](http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/psdparse) <sub>by Telegraphics</sub>

It...

- ... extracts all layers to png images
- ... doesn't flatten the psd file
- ... extracts all layers at the same time
- ... keeps the name of the layer
- ... is available for [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) and [osx](/questions/tagged/osx), but unfortunately not for [linux](/questions/tagged/linux)
- ... is [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) (aka "Free")

---

1. Go to the website, and download the `Windows (32 bit)` version: <sup>*(I assume you're using windows, as you failed to specify the OS in the question)*</sup>
   [image: which file to download]
2. Extract the contents of the downloaded `psdparse-3.6f1-win32.zip` *(right-click --> "Extract All...")* to a new folder
3. Go to the folder where you extracted the zip file. You should see 2 files:
   [image: 2 files]
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>rmb</kbd> *(Right Mouse Button)* on an empty area, and click on "Open command window here"
5. In the command window, type `psdparse` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You should see this:
   [image: psdparse command line options]
6. Type "psdparse -w [location of psd file]", for example: `psdparse -w C:\example.psd`.
7. It should extract the layers and save them as png files in the folder "[name of psd file]_png" in the same location as the psd file, for example: `C:\example_png\`
8. That's it!

---

<sub>*Source: [Take a psd and export all the layers into separate image files without using Photoshop - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/471446/315396)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There is a [PSD.rb](https://github.com/layervault/psd.rb) which is the file parser for Photoshop written in Ruby.

To get the list of components, you can write a script like:

```
require 'psd'

PSD.open('path/to/file.psd') do |psd|
  # Get information about all the available layer comps
  puts psd.layer_comps
end
```

To save same component, you can write:

```
# Save a layer comp
psd.tree.filter_by_comp("Version A").save_as_png('./Version A.png')

# Generate PNG of individual layer group
psd.tree.children_at_path("Group 1").first.to_png
```

To save a specific slice into PNG, it's:

```
psd.slices_by_name('Logo').first.save_as_png('Logo.png') #=> writes Logo.png
```

---

Another tool to consider is [ag-psd](https://github.com/Agamnentzar/ag-psd), it's JavaScript library for reading and writing PSD files. Example script:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { readPsd } from 'ag-psd';

var buffer = fs.readFileSync('my-file.psd');
var psd = readPsd(buffer);

console.log(psd);

fs.writeFileSync('layer-1.png', psd.children[0].canvas.getBuffer());
```